# VS2017 new csproj type not outputting files from VSTemplate

Tags: vsix

If I create a new library based off the new csproj format in VS2017 e.g.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
```

When I create a VSTemplate, then use the template, it creates the project, but none of the files are copied, even though they are located in the template folder.

The one exception I have found is if any of the files are an embedded resource and hence marked like this

```
<ItemGroup>
  <EmbeddedResource Include="App.xaml">       
     <Generator>MSBuild:UpdateDesignTimeXaml</Generator>     
  </EmbeddedResource>   
</ItemGroup>
```

This file will be outputted to the project. But not even the App.xaml.cs comes through.

Any VSTemplate I create using the old csproj format, works as expected.

Comment: I did find this issue reported that seems very similar. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/21751/creating-new-project-from-vs-2017-rc-exported-temp-1.html Still shocked that they are just slapping won't fix over obvious, show stopping bugs.

Comment: I posted an issue with Visual Studio. Just posting the link here for reference: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/61032/vstemplate-with-new-csproj-file-format-does-not-co.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by adding `<CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>` into `<TemplateData>` section in my `.vstemplate`. So for example:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" Type="Project">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>Service Template</Name>
    <Description></Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <ProjectSubType>
    </ProjectSubType>
    <SortOrder>1000</SortOrder>
    <CreateNewFolder>false</CreateNewFolder>
    <DefaultName>NewService</DefaultName>
    <ProvideDefaultName>true</ProvideDefaultName>
    <LocationField>Enabled</LocationField>
    <EnableLocationBrowseButton>true</EnableLocationBrowseButton>
    <CreateInPlace>true</CreateInPlace>
  </TemplateData>
```

Solution found from the [first issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/21751/creating-new-project-from-vs-2017-rc-exported-temp-1.html) you posted in comments.